# #_ present in the code returned from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook

There is a # present in the access token which is not getting parsed properly. This happens when I am using the Facebook PHP connect SDK.

I have seen similar issues being reported by other folks. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I am using php 5.2 and i dont even see the # in $_GET. Does this mean that I need to upgrade PHP or is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with your redirect_uri. See here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

Comment: but whats the solution to the problem?

Comment: I have used the solution being proposed in various blogs, the best one so far is the one which calls for reseting the window.location.hash to empty.